# IdentityServer3: Can it be used "side by side" with existing users/authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, identityserver3

I'm new to SSO, so hopefully what I'm asking makes sense. So my current setup is a `.NET MVC` website using `OWIN`/cookies (`app.UseCookieAuthentication()`) and a custom user table (not `ASP.NET Identity` users).

So I'm wondering if I could add `IdentityServer3` only for external providers, but leave all my existing user/authentication stuff as is for "local users". So I see that you can implement a custom `IUserService` to lookup users against your local database, and I think I got that working, but I'd like to even avoid that. And I'd like to avoid themeing the `IdentityServer` login screen. So something like this:

1. User hits up page with `[Authorize]` attribute.
2. User is redirected to my existing login page (not `IdentityServer` stuff)
3. Then my login page would have the external provider button(s) to login with external providers.

Is that possible? Or do you have to run your local users through `IdentityServer3` also? I noticed I get an error if you don't provide a `IUserService` and don't use `UseInMemoryUsers()` either.

So from following various guides, I have this in my Startup.cs: `app.UseIdentityServer()`, `app.UseCookieAuthentication()`, and `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()` with `Authority` set to my IdentityServer endpoint.

Hopefully that made sense, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna answer my own question if it helps anyone else. The important piece here is `AuthenticationMode` in `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`. `AuthenticationMode.Active` is what will redirect the user to your OIDC provider anytime they hit an action with `[Authorize]`.`AuthenticationMode.Passive` will allow you to use your OIDC provider as an additional authentication method. You want to follow the examples with `ExternalLogin()` and `ExternalLoginCallback()` controller actions that issue challenges to the provider and then match the authenticate user with your local user.